# how to customize the privileges to edit entitlement policies based on the role in admin UI?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I wanted to give privileges to few users to edit  few entitlement policies in wso2 Identity server.Is it posible to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can control the permission of entitlement policy management of users, but cannot be applied per policy in default WSO2 Identity Server.
In WSO2 Identity server management console, you can add a role with appropriate permissions for managing entitlement policies. Click on 'Add' under 'Users and Roles' and select 'Add New Role'. Give a role name and click next to get the permission tree. You can select permission as shown below,
[image]

Comment: Thank you So much Lahiru .Is there any way I can customize the default wso2 IS to apply few user role can modify only   a particular policy?

Comment: Customizing IS server will be difficult(new feature) as it is not typical extension point. A solution that i can think of, is that you control policies from external UI(Use admin service to manage policies) and throttle API calls based on the roles of users. It is also very complex and resource/time consuming.